# Conda won't activate any environment since update

Tags: python, conda

I updated conda and now I have an error not easily found on the web or stackoverflow.

I'm on macOS 10.13.2

I updated conda/hombrew/npm all around the same time and only now vaguely remember noticing that conda(?) was updating futures.

I mention this because it was referenced in an unrelated but similar bug report.

Thanks in advance

Gareth

```
futures                   3.2.0            py27h1b80678_0
```

My error:

```
λ source activate py36
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/logging.py", line 64, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/__init__.py", line 43, in __repr__
    return '%s: %s' % (self.__class__.__name__, text_type(self))
  File "/Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/__init__.py", line 47, in __str__
    return text_type(self.message % self._kwargs)
ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 445
Logged from file exceptions.py, line 724
```

Conda info:

```
λ conda info

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/gyaresu/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/gyaresu/.condarc
          conda version : 4.4.7
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.14.final.0
       base environment : /Users/gyaresu/miniconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/pkgs
                          /Users/gyaresu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/gyaresu/miniconda2/envs
                          /Users/gyaresu/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.7 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.14 Darwin/17.3.0 OSX/10.13.2
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : /Users/gyaresu/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

System Python:

```
λ which python
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python

λ python -V
Python 2.7.14
```

Hombrew info:

```
λ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.4.3
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 987805d3dcd4c8dbc70127399d4ea7aee8e98c21
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: eae0bcacf6aa1592ee0fdc2d424a1c63a0a2d17a
Core tap last commit: 8 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit ivybridge
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.0 build 900
Git: 2.15.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Perl: /usr/local/bin/perl => /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby => /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_51, 1.6.0_65-b14-468
macOS: 10.13.2-x86_64
Xcode: N/A
CLT: 9.2.0.0.1.1510905681
X11: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

Comment: nuked > reinstalled > fixed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a conda' bug. You can update your conda now.

`$conda update conda`

I create new environment and it goes ok ~